# Python: redirect ONLY shared library (C++) stdout to file

Tags: python, shared-libraries, stdout, stderr

I am using a Python library (written in C++) that outputs a lot of messages in the console. Unfortunately the library is closed source, so there is no way to change its behavior. My goal is to write a Python context handler that redirects the library C++ output (both stdout ans stderr) into two files, while leaving the Python output unchanged (shown in the console). This is what I managed to accomplish so far:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

log_dir = Path('./')

class logSaver():
    def __init__(self, logname):
        self.logname = logname
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()

        if self.logname == None:
            self.logpath_out = os.devnull
            self.logpath_err = os.devnull
        else:
            self.logpath_out = log_dir / (logname + "_out.log")
            self.logpath_err = log_dir / (logname + "_err.log")

        self.logfile_out = os.open(self.logpath_out, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT)
        self.logfile_err = os.open(self.logpath_err, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.orig_stdout = sys.stdout # save original stdout
        self.orig_stderr = sys.stderr # save original stderr

        self.new_stdout = os.dup(1)
        self.new_stderr = os.dup(2)

        os.dup2(self.logfile_out, 1)
        os.dup2(self.logfile_err, 2)

        sys.stdout = os.fdopen(self.new_stdout, 'w')
        sys.stderr = os.fdopen(self.new_stderr, 'w')
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()

        sys.stdout = self.orig_stdout # restore original stdout
        sys.stderr = self.orig_stderr # restore original stderr
        
        os.close(self.logfile_out)
        os.close(self.logfile_err)
```

The context handler is then used as follows:

```
with logSaver("log_filename"):
    some_cpp_and_python_code()
```

The result is the creation of two files:

- log_filename_out.log
- log_filename_err.log

that contain all the output produced by the C++ library, while the output produced by Python is shown regularly into the console, and is not written into the log files.

The code works fine, and redirects only the C++ stdout while leaving unchanged the Python `print()` calls, however, for some reason, it works only one time: all subsequent uses of the context handler result in the broken behaviour of the Python `print()` calls, as they are not shown anywhere (console or log files). I suspect the issue might lie in the incorrect restoration of the original stdout and stderr.

How can the code be changed to fix this behaviour?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I would think you'd need another `dup2` call in your exit handler, instead of simply changing numerical descriptors.

Comment: @SergeyA you mean something like `os.dup2(sys.stdout, self.orig_stdout)`?

Comment: @SergeyA Using `os.dup2(self.orig_stdout, 1)` fixed my problem! Thank you Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SergeyA comment, I managed to fix the problem. Here is the final working code for whoever might be interested:

```
class logSaver():
    def __init__(self, logname):
        self.logname = logname
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        if self.logname == None:
            self.logpath_out = os.devnull
            self.logpath_err = os.devnull
        else:
            self.logpath_out = logname + "_out.log"
            self.logpath_err = logname + "_err.log"
        self.logfile_out = os.open(self.logpath_out, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT)
        self.logfile_err = os.open(self.logpath_err, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.orig_stdout = os.dup(1)
        self.orig_stderr = os.dup(2)
        self.new_stdout = os.dup(1)
        self.new_stderr = os.dup(2)
        os.dup2(self.logfile_out, 1)
        os.dup2(self.logfile_err, 2)
        sys.stdout = os.fdopen(self.new_stdout, 'w')
        sys.stderr = os.fdopen(self.new_stderr, 'w')
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()

        os.dup2(self.orig_stdout, 1)
        os.dup2(self.orig_stderr, 2)
        os.close(self.orig_stdout)
        os.close(self.orig_stderr)
        
        os.close(self.logfile_out)
        os.close(self.logfile_err)
```

The problem was that I was restoring the original streams with

```
sys.stdout = self.orig_stdout
```

while the correct way was to do:

```
os.dup2(self.orig_stdout, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to me a bit complicated.
Here is my own version, removing some unusefull and hard to understand code, especially in `__enter__` block.

I put this code in comment, and leave only what appears to be useful.

At the end I added a sample test of the code (for stdout and stderr).

```
# first let's explain that 1 = sys.stdout.fileno()
#                          2 = sys.stderr.fileno()
import sys
import os
class logSaver():
    def __init__(self, logname=None): # set default to None
        self.logname = logname
        sys.stdout.flush() # flushes original stdout
        sys.stderr.flush() # flushes original stderr
        if self.logname == None:
            self.logpath_out = os.devnull
            self.logpath_err = os.devnull
        else:
            self.logpath_out = logname + "_out.log"
            self.logpath_err = logname + "_err.log"
        self.logfile_out = os.open(self.logpath_out, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT) # Attention: will not append
        self.logfile_err = os.open(self.logpath_err, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREAT) # Attention: will not append
        self.orig_stdout = os.dup(1) # creates a new file_descriptor to original stdout
        self.orig_stderr = os.dup(2) # creates a new file_descriptor to original stderr
    
    def __enter__(self):
        # self.new_stdout = os.dup(1) # why do you need a new_stdout? I don't get it
        # self.new_stderr = os.dup(2) # why do you need a new_stderr? I don't get it
        os.dup2(self.logfile_out, 1) # stdout file descriptor points to logfile_out
        os.dup2(self.logfile_err, 2) # stderr file descriptor points to logfile_err
        # sys.stdout = os.fdopen(self.new_stdout, 'w') # why would you do that? target file already opened and pointed to
        # sys.stderr = os.fdopen(self.new_stderr, 'w') # why would you do that? target file already opened and pointed to       

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.flush() # flushes logfile_out
        sys.stderr.flush() # flushes logfile_err

        os.dup2(self.orig_stdout, 1) # stdout file descriptor points to original stdout
        os.dup2(self.orig_stderr, 2) # stderr file descriptor points to original stdout

        os.close(self.orig_stdout) # close duplicate file descriptor to original stdout
        os.close(self.orig_stderr) # close duplicate file descriptor to original stderr
        os.close(self.logfile_out) # close log file logfile_out
        os.close(self.logfile_err) # close log file logfile_err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("first")                              # logs to standard stdout
    os.write(2,"first stderr\n".encode())       # logs to standard stderr
    with logSaver("test"):
        print("here 1")                         # logs to file "test_out.log"
        os.write(2,"here 1 stderr\n".encode())  # logs to file "test_err.log"
    print("there 1")                            # logs to standard stdout
    os.write(2,"there 1 stderr\n".encode())     # logs to standard stderr
    with logSaver("test"):
        print("here 2")                         # delete previous content of file "test_out.log", and logs to it.
        os.write(2,"here 2 stderr\n".encode())  # delete previous content of file "test_err.log", and logs to it.
    print("there 2")                            # logs to standard stdout
    os.write(2,"there 2 stderr\n".encode())     # logs to standard stderr
```